# How to insert code resources in Joomla?

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm making a website using Joomla and i needed to add a custom code in some level(html with js and jquery),I used [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051/) to add that customized code, the point here is that there are some resources that this code uses, like xml file and some images, i want to add these resources some where in the joomla project so it reads it from there(i don't want to hardcode a fixed directory i just want these resources to be ridden from the source), So, where is that place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which case, the worst place to put them would be somewhere like your template folder. To ensure they won't get overridden, I would suggest you put them in the **media** folder, else create a new folder specifically for the resources. Just ensure they are still within the root of your Joomla directory so it won't cause any possible problems should you ever decide to move your site to a different host or something